# fullcalendar UI not displaying

Tags: fullcalendar

I believe i have  everything coded right ,as Dreamweaver shows no Syntax errors, however the fullcalendar UI is not displaying either in Dreamweavers' preview pane, it does however display the div, or in Mozilla Firefox.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"/>
<script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

all files are local
Dreamweaver CC 2014 1.1 and Firefox 36.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one css file `fullcalendar.print.css` please include it. you can use the cdn path `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css`

Check console there might be error of jquery not defined. Include the file in that case. 
cdn path `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js`

For full download fullcalendar [Click here..](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)

Include your files in this sequence.

1. Moment js
2. jQuery js
3. Fullcalendar js

P.s: And make sure each of the file is included properly.

I have created a jsfiddle link on the left menu click on external sources. [Click here for jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wngd5r86/)

Comment: added the .print css file an I'm still having the same problem can i use ' <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>' instead of the cdn path you suggested?

Comment: yes you can use any `CDN` path just check for errors in your browsers console

Comment: Firebug displays these errors in it's counsel 
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 

factory(jQuery, moment);

 
fullcalendar.js (line 15, col 2)
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
 

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

 
demo.html (line 15, col 4)

Comment: Download the jquery from official site and then include that, remember to include stable version https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: it's still not working, Firefox now shows NO errors in its counsel

Comment: i have created jsfiddle link check that out.

Comment: it's still not working , I even copied your code. by the way i'm using this as part of a mock up.

Comment: I think there is some terrible mistake at your end, If you have an live url paste the code there i will check and identify the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by a live url, i don't have a hosting account any ideas on a free place to post my code?